# hightchart annotations is not working

Tags: highcharts

here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4nyu1bsh/14/

I don't know but some how annotations is not working with high chart.

May be possible I use dates on graph ?

and here is code :

```
annotations :  [{
                labelOptions: {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                },
                labels: [{
                    point: {
                        x: 1,
                        y: 1
                    },
                    text:'test',
                }]

            }],
```

Comment: Now I just see it http://jsfiddle.net/4nyu1bsh/44/ but not on point

Answer (score 0):

It's working, this is correct config: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4nyu1bsh/65/

```
mainchart.addAnnotation({
  labels: [{
    point: {
      x: 1220140800000, // timestamp
      y: 48814, // value
      xAxis: 0, // yAxis INDEX
      yAxis: 0 // xAxis INDEX
    },
    text: 'ysssssssssssssssssy'
  }]
});
```